# Does build pipeline requires internate connection to run

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Onprimise AzureDevOps. I am having intranet within the server but no access to internet.

Does the Use Nugget and Nugget installer requires internet to get it success.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Common/packaging-common/nuget/NuGetToolGetter.ts) you will find this code:

```js
async function getLatestMatchVersionInfo(versionSpec: string): Promise<INuGetVersionInfo> {
    taskLib.debug('Querying versions list');

    let versionsUrl = 'https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json';
    let proxyRequestOptions = {
        proxy: taskLib.getHttpProxyConfiguration(versionsUrl)
    };
    let rest: restm.RestClient = new restm.RestClient('vsts-tasks/NuGetToolInstaller', undefined, undefined, proxyRequestOptions);

    let nugetVersions: INuGetVersionInfo[] = (await rest.get<INuGetVersionInfo[]>(versionsUrl, GetRestClientOptions())).result;
    // x.stage is the string representation of the enum, NuGetReleaseStage.Value = number, NuGetReleaseStage[NuGetReleaseStage.Value] = string, NuGetReleaseStage[x.stage] = number
    let releasedVersions: INuGetVersionInfo[] = nugetVersions.filter(x => x.stage.toString() !== NuGetReleaseStage[NuGetReleaseStage.EarlyAccessPreview]);
    let versionStringsFromDist: string[] = releasedVersions.map(x => x.version);

    let version: string = toolLib.evaluateVersions(versionStringsFromDist, versionSpec);
    if (!version)
    {
        taskLib.error(taskLib.loc("Error_NoVersionWasFoundWhichMatches", versionSpec));
        taskLib.error(taskLib.loc("Info_AvailableVersions", releasedVersions.map(x => x.version).join("; ")));
        throw new Error(taskLib.loc("Error_NuGetToolInstallerFailer", NUGET_TOOL_NAME));
    }

    return releasedVersions.find(x => x.version === version);
}
```

And it basically looks for nuget version if it will not find it on local machine. I assume that all this REST calls will not work without internet. So if you do not want to provide access to internet you should use only those versions installed on agents.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej, I think it is feasible to run build pipeline without internet connection. From the description of NuGet tool installer task we can know :

> Acquires a specific version of NuGet from the internet or the **tools
>   cache** and adds it to the PATH.

[image]

So you need to make sure that the nuget version you need is installed on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use [upstream packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops-2019) from the feed in your DevOps server, then your DevOps server machine could just in intranet network.

However, your build agent machine requires internet access, if you to do something that requires to access internet, such as Use Nuget task.